Custom G-code Routine: Ender 3 Hotend Shutting Off
I'm trying to use some handwritten G-code to cut a shape from a styrofoam sheet, for which I've fused a small copper protrusion to the nozzle of an Ender 3. This seems to work magnificently, save for the fact that as soon as beginning the cutting phase of the G-code program, the hotend shuts off. Here is the G-Code:

G28
G0 F1200 Z5
G01 X60
G01 Y60
M104 S175
M109 R175
G0 F300 Z0.25
-- Hotend shuts off here --
G01 Y95
G01 X93
G01 Y80
G01 X63
G01 Y60
G0 F1200 Z5
M104 S0
M109 R0


When I swap the nozzle for an unmodified one, it can do a normal print without any issues.
I've tried this on the latest Creality firmware, as well as the latest bugfix build of Marlin, but the effect is the same. I've tried moving around the point at which the hotend temperature is set, but to no avail.
I'd appreciate any suggestions or explanations as to why this might be happening, thanks!
